# Group by the condition of range of dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, time, group-by

I'm trying to get the SELECT based on grouping not the calendar day but the condition of date ranges (from 5:45 previous day to 5:45 next day). It's kinda confusing for me at this moment:

```
select al, time,  AVG (index) as avg_index, COUNT (code) as cnt
from df
group by al, strftime('%d', time)
```

[image]

Any suggestions how that can be done in SQLlite dialect?

Many thanks!

Comment: share sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract 345 minutes (5 hours 45 minutes) and extract the date:

```
select al, date(datetime(time, '-345 minutes')),
       AVG(index) as avg_index, COUNT(code) as cnt
from df
group by al, date(datetime(time, '-345 minutes'))
```